# unique after_sign_out paths with multiple models with Devise and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a rails 3.2 app with Devise 2.1

I have 2 models using devise (AdminUser and User)

Models:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

I have generated separate views for both models via the devise generator.
views/devise folder for AdminUser (implemented months earlier before new requirement)
views/users folder for User model

After signout, I want to redirect to specific actions that match the devise models. The code below works in application_controller.rb but it is applying to both models which I want to do without:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(user)
  user_landing_path
end
```

Signing out of either model redirects to the same landing page, but i would like to have a unique destination for both devise models.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out what seems to be a solution after looking at some examples here 
http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/03/10/rails-redirect-previous-page-after-devise-sign-in/

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  case resource_or_scope
    when :user, User
      user_landing_path
    when :admin_user, AdminUser
      admin_user_landing_path
    else
      super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things you could do:

```
case user.class
when AdminUser.class
  do_admin_sign_out()
when User.class
  do_user_sign_out()
else
  no_idea_who_you_are()
end
```

or

```
if user.kind_of? AdminUser
  do_admin_thing()
else
  do_user_thing()
end
```

alternatively, you could add an `admin?` check to both models, and check that, ie:

```
if user.admin?
  do_admin_thing()
...
```

I would probably do the later, as this might come up else where, but these are among your options.

Comment: Where would this code go in the context of a devise signout sequence?  I can see the checks working on an ad-hoc basis, but not sure how it fits in this case where I am using controllers in the Devise engine